# HTML header: how do I make text narrow (not broad)?

Tags: html, css

I have been coding for a school project and I came across this problem, where I wanted a header without it being broad. I am new to Stack Overflow and I hope that I'm not asking a really stupid question, but I have not found an answer while searching beforehand.

My code looks like this:

```css
h5 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16;
  font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<h5> <img id="img" src="image0.jpg" height="350" width="600"> <br> Pictures are symbolic. </h5>
```

Is there a command that forces css to make headers narrow? Or do I need to use something else?

Edit: I have found an easier solution by simply not using headers (and adding code directly into html), thanks to the people who helped.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the header being too broad and making it narrow? Perhaps an example image would clarify

Comment: Im sorry I phrased it badly, I was sort of in a rush. I want the text to not be broad (So in html I would use the <b> command, however I don't want it to be broad. The text (that uses h5) is broad nonetheless).

Comment: Wait, you mean "bold". Sorry we didn't pick up on that. I answered the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If what you meant narrow as in narrowing the text inside Header.

You can use 
    **`transform: scaleX(0.7);`**

```css
h5 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16;
}
h5 span{
    display:block;
    transform: scaleX(0.8);/*This one here to scale the text*/
}
```

```html
<h5> <img id="img" src="image0.jpg" height="350" width="600"><br>
     <span>Pictures are symbolic.</span> </h5>
```

Or  a narrow font like

`font-family: "Helvetica Narrow","Arial
Narrow",Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;`

or the [font-stretch property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-width-the-font-stretch-property)

Comment: I have tried your answer, however it only made the text smaller. It remains broad. I may have phrased the original question wrongly. The problem is that I want the text just the way Im writting it now (so not broad).

Comment: Try using 

`transform: scaleY(0.7);`
`transform: scaleY(1.5);`

`transform: scaleX(1.5);`

Comment: I just don't understand what you meant by broad.
If you mean bold, then you can adjust it by `font-weight:500` or `font-weight:600`

Comment: yes @jured100 can you add a screenshot of what exactly you need as we are unable to pick your point

Answer (score 0):

If i guess you are talking about the margin property of h5, to narrow it down? well i modifies your css , see if it serves you and for description , **margin** is the distance between outside objects and the border; **padding** is the space inside the border and the data inside

```css
h5 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

//inserting your image css into here rather than in html
#img
{
height:auto;
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?w=640&ssl=1"> <br>

    <h5> Pictures are symbolic. </h5>
```

Comment: if you want something else comment down here, will see through your problem as it's unclear what are you trying to say in question, or if above answers your question then mark the answer as your question answer or i will modify as you need.

Comment: I cannot insert the picture out of html, as that would give me a lot things to fix (the webpage is already done). I only want h5 to not be broad, to be like normal calibri text (like the one you see here).

Comment: @jured why dont you use width:100%; so that image will resize itself with respect to screen size and make height:auto;

Comment: That actually sounds like a good idea, however I just really liked the idea of having all the pictures the same size...

Answer (score 0):

To make the text in a h5 not bold, all you need to do is add `font-weight: normal;` to the css.

Or, since you're already using `font-size` and `font-family`, you can use the `font` shorthand:

```css
font: 16px 'Calibri';
```

This is short for

```css
font-weight: normal; font-size: 16px; font-family: 'Calibri';
```

Result:

```css
h5 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 16px 'Calibri'; /* here */
}
```

```html
<h5> <img id="img" src="image0.jpg" height="350" width="600"> <br> Pictures are symbolic. </h5>
```

Note that you also had `16` for a font size in the CSS. I corrected that to `16px`, so you may notice a difference in size!